# Custom class that inherits from UITextField does not work (with custom init) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, initialization, uitextfield

So the title says it all. I am trying to create a class that explicitly inherits from UITextField. This is because I want to do some customization to my UITextFields. My main goal though, is to create a custom initializer for the class, however, I run into trouble by doing so.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    //Class variables

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder, other:String) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        println("Instantiated")
        println(other)

    }
}
```

But the compiler complains with: `'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UITextField'`. Then I go ahead and apply the suggested fix for the problem, and it adds the following code right below my required init code:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

My code above never prints "Instantiated"

Could you please help me out? My ideal class would receive at least another 2 arguments in the initializer (besides the coder-NSCoder one). I don't get why I can't get this to work (maybe I am too used to Java, where doing this is easier).

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Cheers!

Comment: Are you using storyboard or do you instantiate it programmatically?

Comment: I am using the storyboard. I want to code some methods as well. I am aware that I can use an extension but it would be best suited for my needs to just create a separate class

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    init(frame: CGRect, arg1: CGFloat, arg2: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = arg1
        print(arg2)
        print("Instantiated")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

`required init(coder)` is mandatory even if you don't use it.

If your text field is added in storyboard, don't forget to change the class of that field to `CustomTextField` in Identity Inspector and you can use the code below to customize some things:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        // Set other stuff like font color etc.

        print("Instantiated")
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to keep the frame I have in the storyboard for its' size? I just want to add some customization such as border color and font type, maybe an image as well, but I want everything else to be inherited by default from the super class' init. Could this be achieved? thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer if you're using storyboard.

Comment: It does the println message but it does not change the cornerRadius or the color... Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Change the borderWidth to 1.0 and it should change

Comment: I was doing it (I read somewhere that you had to set the border width before changing the cornerRadius) and it was not the problem. in my viewDidLoad method I was resetting the color and everything (I deleted my functionality there and it worked). This leads me to my last question. So, this means that awakeFromNib() executes before viewDidLoad, am I right? Is it the first method to load after the splash screen exits from the stack of views? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the lifecycle of a view controller, but it seems the storyboard is loaded before `viewDidLoad`. I tested it by printing a message in `viewDidLoad` and it comes after the "Instantiated" we had in the custom text field. It sounds logical as well to load things first from storyboard before loading the view of the view controller. Hope that helped you! Oh and if the answer answered your question, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: You really saved me some headaches man! I appreciate your help. Have a great rest of your day!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the storyboard you won't need custom or convenience initializers, just override the super initializer and start your variables before call supper, as in the code below.

```
import UIKit

class MyTextView: UITextView {

    var myValue:Int
    var myText:String


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        myText = String()
        myValue = Int()
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    }

}
```

Comment: the compiler does not complain anymore but whenever I start the app it crashes. It flags the fatalError("init(coder:)" has not been implemented) line. I am assigning the CustomTextField class to a UITextField in my storyboard btw. Thanks

Comment: You will need to pass the frame as well, I update the code to fix it

Comment: Since I am using the storyboard, I would like to keep the size of my UITextField I have in there. Could this be achieved?

Comment: If you are using storyboard you don't need custom initializers you just need to override the super ones to start your variables, I update the code for you

Comment: If you are using storyboard you have to override `init(coder:)`, as that is the initialiser used by storyboard